# Custom Jquery Slider | Click Menu Item To Change Silde

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code/example: http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/14/

The slider works perfectly, all I'm after now is if you were to click on any of the "news-items" say "node 1" for example the corresponding image will render - same for "node 2"

```
// News Article Slideshow
  var periodToChangeSlide = 5000;
  var pp_slideshow = undefined;
  var currentPage = 0;

  $('#news-feature-img-wrap li').css('display','list-item').slice(1).css('display','none');
  $('#news-items li:first').addClass('active');

  $("#news-feature-wrap #news-items li").click( function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(index);
  toShow.show();
  toShow.siblings().hide();
  currentPage = index;
  $.stopSlideshow();
  });

  $.startSlideshow = function(){
    if(typeof pp_slideshow == 'undefined'){
    pp_slideshow = setInterval($.startSlideshow, periodToChangeSlide);
  } else {
    $.changePage();
    }
  }

  $.stopSlideshow = function(){
    clearInterval(pp_slideshow);
    pp_slideshow= undefined;
  }
  $.changePage = function(){
    var numSlides= $('#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li').length;
    currentPage = (currentPage + 1) % numSlides;
    var menu = $('#news-feature-wrap #news-items li').eq(currentPage);
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.siblings().removeClass('active');

    var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(currentPage);
    toShow.show();
    toShow.siblings().hide();
  }

  $.startSlideshow();
```

Comment: Questions is not clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your `$.changePage` function slightly to accept an internal parameter:

```
$.changePage = function(internal) { //add this optional parameter
  var numSlides= $('#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li').length;
  if (typeof internal == 'undefined') currentPage = (currentPage + 1) % numSlides; //add this conditional
  else currentPage = internal; //and this else
  ...
```

Then you can just add a simple event listener:

```
$('#news-items').on('click', 'li', function() {
    //stop and restart to reset the interval
    $.stopSlideshow();
    $.changePage($(this).index());
    $.startSlideshow();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/27/)

For jQuery `1.4.3`-`1.6.4`:

```
$('#news-items').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    //stop and restart to reset the interval
    $.stopSlideshow();
    $.changePage($(this).index());
    $.startSlideshow();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/25/)

Comment: Nearly there mate - only issue is that the "active" class has now been removed from the first list item within "news-items"

Comment: @Filth when does that happen? Whenever I click to change or wait for it to change automatically, the `active` class follows the corresponding image.

Comment: I made the `.active` background green just for testing, check if it doesn't work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/17/

Comment: All good - it does what I want it to just some minor bugs on my end - many thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure but that was most likely because you had set the wrapper to `onLoad`, and your code was setting the `active` only when all images are loaded in the new version of the fiddle -- maybe you can start the first item with the active class already in the markup if that's a problem. `=]`

Comment: Firefox is giving me the error: "$("news-items").on" is not a function

Comment: Weird, jQuery is included in your page and you didn't forget the `#` before `news-items` right. Oh wait, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: `.on` is for jQuery 1.7+, if you're using 1.4.3-1.6.4 then you can use delegate: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/19/

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Yeah, either upgrade that `1.6.1` to `1.7.2` or change the `.on` by `.delegate` as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/20/).

Comment: @Fabrico Have a look at this - the slider nav onclick function does not work when you have 4 items: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/17/

Comment: @Filth where are the 4 items? Gimme a minute to review it.

Comment: @Fabrico - http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/21/ if you click on node 4 then try to click node 1 it won't let you.

Comment: That's really weird. Give me a couple minutes to debug.

Comment: @Filth Found the problem, heh, when you pass the index `0` my `if` was returning false.. Just gotta fix this line: `if (internal === undefined) currentPage = (currentPage + 1) % numSlides; //add this conditional` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6j4cT/22/)

Comment: Woot!! Solution and we are done and dusted!! :-D

Comment: No problem, fixed the answer's code and fiddles as well. Sorry for the nub mistake/headache. `:P`

Comment: haha no worries - we got it working in the end! :-D

Comment: @Filth I just made another little upgrade, `if (typeof internal == 'undefined')` should be more sturdy and less error-prone so you don't run in problems in the future. `=]`

Comment: #Fabrico Thanks mate - have made the change :-D